# Looking for an one file AOP proxy generator

Tags: c#, aop, dynamic-proxy

I'm working on an automatic pageable collection for WPF. I'm using internally the excellent library LinFu.DynamicProxy. I would like to minimize the dependencies, and I did not find any "one file" solution implementyng a DynamicProxy generator, so I would like to ask if you are aware of such a component.

Thanks,

Felice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution writing one myself, really bound to the functionality I actually need. [Here is the code for reference](https://github.com/FelicePollano/FlyFetch/blob/master/FlyFetch/ProxyFactory.cs).